# Solving equations using lists of data

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have a list of pairs of numbers that represent empirical data for U(n) e.g. {{n1,U1}, {n2,U2},...}.

Is there a way to use this discrete data set to solve something along the lines of:

```
NSolve[A = n + B*U[n], n]
```

I've tried splitting the list into individual lists of U values and n values and defining a pseudo continuous function:

```
U[n_?NumberQ] := Us[[Position[ns, Nearest[ns, n][[1]]][[1]]]]
```

but the solving functions don't seem to like that. Is there an elegant way to do this or is fitting the data the only workable solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason for not wanting to use fitting or interpolation?

Comment: The data has some near discontinuities and generally doesn't follow the trend of something that can be fit well i.e. with a simple polynomial, exponential, etc. And from my searching it seems that solving with piecewise functions isn't very easy either.

Comment: also `Interpolation`. set 
`InterpolationOrder -> 1`